# Using select box to scroll to a position on the page

Tags: jquery, scroll, drop-down-menu

I have the following select box:

```
 <select id="selectBox" >
 <option value="section01">section01</option>
 <option value="section02">section02</option>
 <option value="section03">section03</option>
 </select>
```

And I have the following sections on the page:

```
 <div class="page" id="section01">
  Some text here
 </div>


 <div class="page" id="section02">
  Some text here
 </div>


 <div class="page" id="section03">
  More text here
 </div>
```

What I'd like to do is have the user select something from the scroll box and then have the page automatically scroll to the proper section.

I'm assuming I can use jquery's scrollTo() method -- but I'm not sure how to grab the option value in the select box -- and then to actual move the web page down to the proper DIV section.

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectBox').change(function () {
        window.location.hash = '#' + $(this).val();
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qJm5D/1/

Comment: Wow -- that's exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to smoothly animate the scrolldown (instead of the immediate jump)?

Comment: Try this Bobby: **http://jsfiddle.net/qJm5D/2/** using `.animate()` and `scrollTo()` for a smooth transition

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.selectBox').change(function() {
    $(".selectBox option:selected").val();
    // Here you can trigger your scrollto function
});
```

Put the code in document ready and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var theDiv = $('#'+$(this).val()).offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: theDiv
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgQFf/)